# The result of json_decode is valid but individual fields are nulls in PHP?

Tags: php

In the following PHP code

```
<?php
$in = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$out->captcha = $in->captcha_code;
$out->name = $in->name;
?>
```

$in has the following value:

```
"in": {
  "name": "John Smith",
  "captcha_code": "03AL4dnxpzq1_rgDGri__waXDSp-951zkitA33V3LQ4kU7kDpsC_tKWK23Z_wyQXdAatEK_Nju1rHVfB4l2IRc8cofCNeSscIvAEC4VeSzgRa45x5d-GWXnAxdgSKQd8MkiUYaZw8h8ECjBLgWthseFd1L4YAPqAT893SOuHLQPd5z9JhJuNgPMcEPuAuBkYCIALcSzR0k6OHwMfgAaNvJ3nMYH2H6iRZeGnWDvXUfCE13w_VGSV3453I7qg3HqhB3t6W2fsH-I034ei0HG_PwMmB0blYNPTcTHA"
};
```

but $in->captcha_code and $in->name (and so $out) are nulls. What is wrong?

Comment: `captcha_code` does not exist in your object.

Comment: what does `$in['in']['name']` produce?

Comment: @u_mulder it exists, I corrected the text.

Comment: Then see anwser below.

Comment: @whitelined yes, even $in['name'] works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP function [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) accepts two parameters, number one being the JSON (string) you want to decode, and the other one (boolean) tells the function do you want to return it as an associative array or an object of type `stdClass`, it defaults to false, true means that you want it as an array.

Since you added the second parameter as `true` it will return it as an array, so you cannot use `->` to access parameters in that JSON.

So, the correct code for your problem is

```
<?php
    $in = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    $out->captcha = $in['in']['captcha_code'];
    $out->name = $in['in']['name'];
?>
```

Also, usually the best way to see what a variable holds is to print it's contents using [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) like so:

```
<?php
    $in = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($in); die();
    //OR what I prefer
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($in); die();

    //$out->captcha = $in['in']['captcha_code'];
    //$out->name = $in['in']['name'];
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You decode json as array and captcha_code not exist in json, Use this:

```
$out->captcha = $in['in']['captcha_code']; // not exist. just email and name is exist
$out->name = $in['in']['name'];
```

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter for json_decode is for assoc, 'When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.'.

Since you're trying to access the data as an object, remove the 'true' from json_decode. If you leave it as true, treat the return as an array, so you would access the data using square brackets.

e.g.
$in = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

You would treat the data as an array
$out->captcha = $in['in']['captcha_code']

$in = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

You would treat the data as an object
$out->captcha = $in->in->captcha_code